# Добавление printf(), в код заставляет его работать, как исправить? язык C

Tags: c, указатели, память

При отладке кода заметил такую странность, если в файле task на 20 строке написать printf("+++++"), то программа работает без ошибок, иначе просто зависает.

О программе:
Программа должна считать два файла(A.txt, B.txt) и сложить их значения в динамические массивы. В файле task. содержится функция read, в которой и происходит ошибка. На 20 строке файла task.c если написать printf("+++++")(если поставить один плюсик вместо 5 то программа виснет), то программа работает исправно и выводит значения файлов, если же убрать или закоментировать эту строчку, то программа выводит значение 1ого и зависает(перестает что либо выводить в консоль, при этом винда не ругается по типу "программа не отвечает")

Для меня это выглядит как какая-то магия. Буду рад если подскажит почему это происходит

P.s я заметил, что эта ошибка связана с fclose в конце функции read в task.c(перенесен в функцию error), если закрывать файл в функции error(смотри p.s в конце поста), тогда эта ошибка исчезает, однако это все равно не объясняет ее природы

libs.h

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int read(FILE *in, int **mas, size_t *len);
void print(int *mas, size_t len);
int error(int state);
```

main.c

```
#include "libs.h" 

int main(void){
    int * arr1 = NULL;
    int * arr2 = NULL;
    size_t n1  = 0;
    size_t n2  = 0;
    FILE * in;


    in = fopen("A.txt","r");
    if(error(read(in, &arr1, &n1))!=1){fclose(in);return 0;}
    print(arr1, n1);

    in = fopen("B.txt","r");
    if(error(read(in, &arr2, &n2))!=1){fclose(in);return 0;}
    print(arr2, n2);


    free(arr1);
    free(arr2);

    return 0;
}
```

task.c

```
#include "libs.h"

int read(FILE *in, int **mas, size_t *len){
    int size = 2;

    if (in == NULL) 
        return -1;

    *mas = (int *)malloc(size*sizeof(int));

    if(*mas==NULL)
        return -4;

    if(fscanf(in, "%d", &(*mas)[*len])!=1){
        if(!feof(in))
            return -2;
        return -3;
    }

    printf("++++++++");    //<-------------Вот здесь ошибка

    *len=1;

    while(fscanf(in, "%d", &(*mas)[*len])==1) 
        *len+=1;
        if(size==*len){
            size*=2;
            *mas = (int *)realloc(*mas, size*sizeof(int));
            if(*mas==NULL)
                return -4;
        }

    if (!feof(in))
        return -3;
    
    return 0;
}

void print(int mas[], size_t len){
    for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
        printf("%d ", mas[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int error(int state){
    switch(state){
        case -1:
            printf("File not found\n");
            return 0;
        case -2:
            printf("File contains non digit symbols\n");
            return 0;
        case -3:
            printf("Empty file\n");
            return 0;
        case -4:
            printf("Memory allocation error\n");
            return 0;
        }
    return 1;
}
```

p.s

```
int error(FILE *in, int state){
    switch(state){
        case -1:
            printf("File not found\n");
            return 0;
        case -2:
            printf("File contains non digit symbols\n");
            fclose(in);
            return 0;
        case -3:
            printf("Empty file\n");
            fclose(in);
            return 0;
        case -4:
            printf("Memory allocation error\n");
            fclose(in);
            return 0;
        }
    return 1;
}
```

А в main.c переписаны строчки(для двух файлов)
`if(error(in, read(in, &arr1, &n1))!=1)return 0;`
в соостветствии с изменениями в error

Comment: Запустил ваш код. Как первую, так и вторую версии. В обоих случаях работает без ошибок вне зависимости от наличия `printf`. Приведите, пожалуйста, в вопрос содержимое файлов

Comment: Такая ошибка в 99% случаев связана с некорректной работой с памятью — где-то, например, выход за пределы выделенной памяти или что-то подобное... В результате всех изменений исходников по сути непонятно, каким был *первоначальный* не работающий код, так что неясно, с чем разбираться, чтоб воспроизвести ошибку.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

А ларчик просто открывался... Ломать замок не требовалось.

```
while(fscanf(in, "%d", &(*mas)[*len])==1) 
    *len+=1;
    if(size==*len){
        size*=2;
        *mas = (int *)realloc(*mas, size*sizeof(int));
        if(*mas==NULL)
            return -4;
    }
```

Что вы делаете тут? Пишете в выделенные 2 байта в памяти всё, что ни есть в файле. И только по завершении цикла якобы пытаетесь массив увеличить.

Наверное, все же надо форматировать код правильно

```
while(fscanf(in, "%d", &(*mas)[*len])==1) 
    *len+=1;
if(size==*len){
    size*=2;
    *mas = (int *)realloc(*mas, size*sizeof(int));
    if(*mas==NULL)
        return -4;
}
```

и ошибка сразу станет видна. Вы же явно хотели так:

```
while(fscanf(in, "%d", &(*mas)[*len])==1) 
{
    *len+=1;
    if(size==*len){
        size*=2;
        *mas = (int *)realloc(*mas, size*sizeof(int));
        if(*mas==NULL)
            return -4;
    }
}
```

Вот, как я и говорил с самого начала — пишете в память за пределами выделенных областей...